# HTML code transfer?

Tags: html

Ok, so I was wondering if it was possible to use the code

```
<script type="text/HTML" src="Other.HTML">
```

to get one bit of code from one HTML file to another? 
EDIT: Ok, just tried it. No luck, all I am getting is a blank screen. Let me rephrase it in is there any way to make this possible.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: This question represents a basic misunderstanding of HTML and shows no effort by the poster, despite containing all code necessary to answer the question.

Comment: Oh please. It's a fine question, and an original attempt. (It's not possible, though, @XanaWarriors; there is actually no way to do this without a server-side language.)

Comment: Actually Lee Taylor, it is, because now I am asking for advice to do this, seeing as the code I gave was not successful. Before I had asked if anyone thought it would work, and am now asking if anyone can help me get a way to MAKE IT work.

Comment: +1 to @Vamshi for the only constructive response. This community is becoming more depressing every day.

Comment: Welcome to the world of dynamic programming..

Answer (score 2):

Pure HTML (without JavaScript) cannot load in another page on it's own.  However, you can use PHP, SHTML, or JavaScript to obtain another page and load it into the page.

**PHP**

Make sure that your HTML file has been renamed with the .php extension. Then you can add the following line where you want to add the HTML file:

```
<?php include('some_file_name.html'); ?>
```

As long as `some_file_name` exists, that page will load in where the PHP tag is.

**SHTML**

Make sure that your HTML file has been renamed with the .shtml extension. Then you can add the following line where you want to add the HTML file:

```
<!--#include virtual="some_file_name.html" -->
```

Again, as long as `some_file_name` exists, the page will load in the page at that. Be sure to watch for spacing, especially between the second dash and `#`, as the line of code will break if there is a space.

**JavaScript**

The plus side of using JavaScript is that you can keep your HTML file a .html file.  However, more code is needed to load in the included file:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includeThis").load("some_file_name.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
...
<div id="includeThis"></div>
```

This will create a function that will load `some_file_name.html` where the div id of `includeThis` is located.  This contains more overhead, but you can keep your .html file extension.

Comment: Ok, this did work, however it brought over the whole file. I was wondering if I could move only the variables.

Comment: What do you mean by a "variable"? You mean only a portion of the page?

Comment: As long as you don't have any scripts in the file, you can select specific elements to load with any generic/specific element selector like this:  `$("#includeThis").load("some_file_name.html #elementID")` <-- Take special note of the SPACE in between the URL and the selector.  `#elementID` could be the ID of a specific `<div>` or it could be `.elementClass` that selects multiple elements with the same class to be loaded.

Comment: @Deryck Wow, I learned something new based off of my own answer. Never knew you could do that before; I was always using PHP "functions" that held the content I needed!

Comment: haha it's very touchy though if you end up with a script inside it'll throw a fit but otherwise it's a handy little tool.